# Is it safe to use sha1(md5($password)) and does it make any difference?

Tags: php, hash

Can I use `sha1(md5($password))` for better password hashing, and will it be harder to hack? Or will the security of the hash be the same?

Comment: Using mutliple hash is bad practice, you should always use the `password_hash` php function to hash your password :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Oh thank you very much.I did not know about that function.Could please post that as answer so other would see @AdrianTombu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using multiple hash is bad practice, you should always use the `password_hash` php function to hash your passwords :)

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php